# I want to send multiple variables from JavaScript function to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I have fetch form data inside function.I want to send all
     variables having data to be send to next page .Please tell me how to do it

```
function form_values() {
    var jsvar = document.myform1.text_quest.value;

    alert(jsvar); // test

    $('select[name="dropdwn"]').each(function() {
        alert(($(this).val()));
    });

    var cal = document.getElementById("otherAnswer").value;
    alert(cal);

    var chk = [];
    $(':radio:checked').each(function() {
        //alert($(this).val());
        chk.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(chk);

    $('[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val())
    });
} //End of function
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your data, for sure. Do you want to send them to a page or do you want to send them to the server to be saved or something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use localStorage to store the values in a json object, and use them in any of your scripts?

For example, in your form_values():

```
var formData = {};

$('select[name="dropdwn"]').each(function() {
   formData.dropdwn = $(this).val();
});
```

Then on form submit:

```
localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));
```

Then from another javascript file:

```
var formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData'));
console.log(formData.dropdwn); // logs your value
```

Of course, make sure you check if formData exists on localStorage before trying to get a value from it.

Comment: It's evident that you are just trying to help out the OP, but this doesn't not answer the question. It is a better fit as a comment. You haven't got 50 reputation points yet, so you can't leave comments. Please do not abuse the system by posting comments as answers.

Comment: what is localStorage here?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `serialize()` in jquery.
For example:

```
url:'your_file.php?'+serialize();
```

This will send all the form values to that file.
For more details check [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Did you try this? @Ronny

Comment: no i am new to javascript can u plz give me code bt plz first have a look at my code

Comment: ya i have understood..but you told all the form values to other page.What is that page?where you calling? @Ronny

Comment: i have a page containing form.I created a function to fetch all data of inputs and now i want to send all values to another page on submit.Actually I have 3 forms and i have to send data of all forms when the 3 form is completed.So i thought to store values of form in function n pass the function when submit